# How to do right click table row on netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, right-click

[image]

into something like this when I right click the row.after I clicked view profile it will popup and new jFrame and display his profile. i am using GUI builder. sorry for being noob. i'm still beginner.it's hard to find on google how to do right click thing.

[image]

**UPDATE2**

I created the menu now but how to get the Student ID cell only... this is my code

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("View Profile");
    JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Delete");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(studentList.this, "Testing");
        }
    });
    jPopupMenu1.add(item);
    jPopupMenu1.add(item2);
```

and on my MouseReleased

```
private void tableMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    int r = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    if (r >= 0 && r < table.getRowCount()) {
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
    } else {
        table.clearSelection();
    }

    int rowindex = table.getSelectedRow();
    if (rowindex < 0) {
        return;
    }


    if (evt.isPopupTrigger() && evt.getComponent() instanceof JTable ) {
        jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29)

You will also want to take a look at [How to use menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: hello do you know how to get the value of the selected studentID?

Comment: i figured it out using this `private Object GetData(JTable table, int row_index, int col_index) {
        return table.getModel().getValueAt(row_index, col_index);
    }` and calling it `Object obj1 = GetData(table, rowindex, 0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,obj1);`